# Implementing WillN in GoogleMock?

Tags: c++, googlemock

Is there a neater and/or briefer way to set multiple identical actions than repeated use of `WillOnce`?  Is there a way for `WillRepeatedly` to have a cardinality, for example?

I can only find examples that chain `WillOnce` potentially followed by a single `WillRepeatedly`, which is less than ideal for situations where I may want to return a value the first N times a function is called and then return a different value the last time, e.g. using a mock to represent obj in the following example and have it loop N times:

```
while (obj.IsDone())
{
    SomeAction(obj.NextItem());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Times`](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CheatSheet#Cardinalities).

```
// This is the final call
EXPECT_CALL(obj, IsDone())
  .WillOnce(Return(true));
// These are the intermediate calls
EXPECT_CALL(obj, IsDone())
  .Times(N)
  .WillRepeatedly(Return(false))
  .RetiresOnSaturation();
```

The mock object's `IsDone` method will return false the first *N* times it's called. After that, the most recent expectation will have been satisfied, so we instruct it to no longer apply by using [`RetiresOnSaturation`](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook#Controlling_When_an_Expectation_Retires). Subsequent calls to `IsDone` will be handled by the first expectation, causing it to return true. If it's called any more times, the test will fail.

If you omit `RetiresOnSaturation`, then the second expectation will continue to apply; it will continue returning false, and you'll get messages alerting you that the "over-saturated and active" expectation is failing.

Comment: How is precedence established between those two?  Does an expectation with `RetiresOnSaturation` automatically take precedence over those without?

Comment: The most recently defined expectation that matches a particular call is the one that's applied. That's why my example defines them in the reverse order from the order they're expected to be called. `RetiresOnSaturation` simply ensures the the second expectation "gets out of the way" once it's been satisfied by *N* calls, allowing the first expectation to take over. To GMock, the `obj.IsDone()` call matches both expectations since there's no parameter value to differentiate them. It just takes whichever expectation was defined most recently and is still active.